# Angular MVC ajax calls 404 not found

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to angular and trying to make a call to perform crud operations from angular to a newly created mvc webapi controller... cannot get around the 404 not found on the get right now.  Looking for some guidance from the pros, thanks!

**Angular:**

```
angular.module('PersonApp').service('PersonService', ['$http', function` ($http) {

    var PersonService = {};
    var urlBase = '/api/PersonApi/';

    PersonService.getPersons = function () {
        console.log(urlBase);
        return $http.get(urlBase);
    };

    PersonService.upsertPerson = function (person) {
        return $http.post(urlBase, person); //must have ,person !!!!!!!!!!
    };

    PersonService.removePerson = function (id) {
        return $http.delete(urlBase + id);
    };

    return PersonService;

}]);
```

**PersonApi.cs api:**

```
public class PersonApi : ApiController
{
    TutorialDataEntities ef_Db = new TutorialDataEntities();
    Repository.Repository PersonRepository = new Repository.Repository();

    [Route("api/PersonApi/{person}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpsertPerson([FromBody]DTOPerson person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // and if you have any other checks
        {
            var result = PersonRepository.UpsertPerson(person);
            formatDate(result.birthDate);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, result);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    [Route("api/PersonApi/{id}")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage RemovePerson([FromUri]int id)
    {
        PersonRepository.RemovePerson(id);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    [Route("api/PersonApi/")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetPersons()
    {
        var result = PersonRepository.GetAllPersons();
        foreach (var person in result)
        {
            formatDate(person.birthDate);
        }

        if (result == null)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);

    }

    private DateTime formatDate(DateTime date)
    {
        return Convert.ToDateTime(date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    }
}
```

My solution explorer:

[image]

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Routeconfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't your controller class need to be named PersonApiController?

Comment: @Lex, for convention-based routing, yes, but OP is using attribute routing.

Comment: @tshoemake, is attribute routing enabled.

Comment: @Nkosi As far as I am aware, attribute based routing still requires the Controller to be part of the class name. Attribute based routing just means you don't have to define route templates.

Comment: @Nkosi not sure, where do i check?

Comment: @Nkosi i added webapiconfig and routeconfig in op

Comment: @Lex, No. one of the purposes for its introduction was to get away from that and allows more flexibility.

Comment: @tshoemake, yes from your update it is enabled `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

Comment: @Lex i tried changing the name to PersonApiController and still same 404 error, thank you though

Comment: @tshoemake, can you share your code(git/bitbuck). so i create actual scenario

Comment: @NeerajSharma, this code is still in development and i havent committed changes to my git yet... it also uses a local database

Comment: @tshoemake, i will try this one

Comment: I added this line to my global.asax.cs and it actually hit a breakpoint in my webapiconfig file now.. GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);  still same error however

Comment: The previous comment and @Lex was correct in that when i changed to PersonApiController it was fixed. Lex, add your answer (and also include the insertion into the global) and i will mark it correct. Thanks everyone.